# Jquery can not transfer value into Hidden Input for some users

Tags: jquery, drupal, input, hiddenfield

I'm smashing my head against the wall because of this problem.

I have a drupal site with a form cntaining a hidden field. Upon click on a div, I write a value into a hidden field which looks like this:

```
<input type="hidden" value="" name="field_body_image[und][0][value]">
```

And then I perform this JQuery:

```
$('input[name="field_klasse_tid[und][0][value]"').attr('value', tid);
```

Usually it works. But not for all users. Some users fail this simple task.
Even

```
$('input[name="field_klasse_tid[und][0][value]"').val(tid);
```

fails for them. It is super weird, JQuery just seems to fail for some users, every other JQuery code on site works for them. What is it with these hidden fields?
I hope some of you have an idea, because I'm running out of time : /
Thank you!

Comment: Not enough known. Could be caused by error thrown by something not even related to this for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jQuery selector is wrong - it has an open `[` but not a close `]`.

```
$('input[name="field_klasse_tid[und][0][value]"').attr('value', tid);
```

It should be:

```
$('input[name="field_klasse_tid[und][0][value]"]').attr('value', tid);
```

Comment: Wow, I can not believe it was something like this. Sometimes you need another pair of eyes... thank you very much!
It is still weird though, that it works for most people!